# C# format float to show 2 places before and after decimal point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a time board and want to show time as 01:24 for example.
My current code:

```
timeInGame.ToString("F2").Replace(".",":");
```

This code returns 1:24 .

Comment: Note that 1.5 == 1:30. I'd be very wary of pretending that the decimal digits are minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the format explicitly:

```
timeInGame.ToString("00.00").Replace(".",":");
```

Note however that it is incorrect to pretend that decimal numbers map to minutes:seconds or hours:minutes, e.g. 1.5 == 1:30.

Comment: I never realized it. It is minutes:seconds, minute part can go above 60 since it is for a football game. I modified it as

`        timeInGame = (gameLengthInGame / gameLengthReal) * time;
        int minutes = (int)timeInGame;
        float minutesAndSeconds = minutes + (((timeInGame % 1) * 60) / 100);
        tm.text = minutesAndSeconds.ToString("00.00").Replace(".", ":"); `
Is there a more efficient way for doing the same thing?

Comment: @SengunSipahi best is to store minutes and seconds separately and format separately.